# How to make a toggle list vue-select?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-select

I need to make sure that when you click on an already active option, it becomes deselect.

`<v-select class="form-control" name="language" v-model="language" id="language" :options="['English', 'Polish']" :clearable="false" :searchable="false" :multiple="true" :closeOnSelect="false"></v-select>`

[Photo Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTddX.png)

I could not find information on this on the Internet and in the documentation, so I hope for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any built in way or a prop to deselect items for the `vue-select` package, however there are two ways of going about it:

1)You can use the (option:selecting) event to filter the array yourself, therby deselecting that option. Checkout the example below.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <v-select
         class="form-control"
         name="language"
         v-model="language"
         id="language"
         :options="['English', 'Polish']"
         :clearable="false"
         :searchable="false"
         :multiple="true"
         :closeOnSelect="false"
         @option:selecting="handleDeselect"
      ></v-select>
      <div class="mt-40">Languages is : {{ language }}</div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import vSelect from "vue-select";
import "vue-select/dist/vue-select.css";
export default {
   components: { vSelect },
   data() {
      return {
         language: ["English"],
      };
   },
   methods: {
      handleDeselect(e) {
         // Check if the lagueage array contains the selected element (e)
         // If so, filter the language array
         if (this.language.includes(e)) {
            this.language = this.language.filter((el) => {
               return el != e;
            });
         }
      },
   },
};
</script>
```

2)Use the `vue-multiselect` package which offers deselecting out of the box (easiest & my preferred way)